# Why does my mesh disappear wholly when only part of it is out of the screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use the following code to create a strip-shaped plane.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DynamicPlane : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject _plane;
    private Mesh _planeMesh;
    private MeshRenderer _planMeshRenderer;
    private List<Vector3> _planeMeshVertices;
    private int[] _planeMeshIndices;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _plane = new GameObject("My Plane");
        _plane.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        _plane.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        _planeMeshVertices = new List<Vector3>() { Vector3.zero, Vector3.zero, Vector3.zero, Vector3.zero };
        _planeMeshIndices = new int[6] { 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3 };
        _planeMesh = new Mesh();
        _planeMesh.SetVertices(_planeMeshVertices);
        _planeMesh.SetIndices(_planeMeshIndices, MeshTopology.Triangles, 0);
        _plane.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh = _planeMesh;
        _planMeshRenderer = _plane.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        _planeMeshVertices[0] = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
        _planeMeshVertices[1] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        _planeMeshVertices[2] = new Vector3(1, 0, 50);
        _planeMeshVertices[3] = new Vector3(0, 0, 50);
        _planeMesh.SetVertices(_planeMeshVertices);
    }

}
```

I set vertices in Update() because in a real project I need to dynamically change the position of vertices.

Start the game and check the Scene view. The purple strip is my plane created by code and the white plane is a primitive. The strip disappears wholly when only a tiny part of it is out of the screen. The white plane is normal. Why does this happen?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

Unity culls of objects that are off-screen by using the [`Render.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html) that are basically the [`Mesh.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bounds.html) but with applied local transformations (position, rotation, scale).

The moment you are creating the mesh via

```c#
_planeMesh = new Mesh();
```

this mesh is empty and gets default bounds (center `0,0,0` and extends `0,0,0`).

Later when you change the vetices you do not calculate new bounds but still use the initial ones.

Therefore you will have noted that the "wrong" culling actually only happens if the bottom left corner (being on `0,0,0`) leaves the screen since Unity thinks that this is all of your mesh.

[image]

#### Solution

Anytime you change something in the mesh you should call [`RecalculateBounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateBounds.html) in order to update the bounds.

```c#
void Update()
{
    _planeMeshVertices[0] = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    _planeMeshVertices[1] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    _planeMeshVertices[2] = new Vector3(1, 0, 50);
    _planeMeshVertices[3] = new Vector3(0, 0, 50);
    _planeMesh.SetVertices(_planeMeshVertices);

    _planeMesh.RecalculateBounds();
}
```

[image]